# How to send parameters when need to call http post call ?

Tags: android

I need to use some service. 
The service method that i need to call need to get two parameters 
    1. int 
    2. some enum

I don't know how to send those parameters and how to make this call. 
I wanted to use this code

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);        
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", val1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", val2);          
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse p = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

But this code can't send int as parameter ( only string ) 
The second parameter ( that is some enum ) i think that i can send as string and the service in the other side will translate this string to enum ( am i right ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf` for an `int` and the `toString` method of an `Enum` (which returns the name of the `Enum` as a `String`).

How the server deals with this data depends on how it was coded.

Answer (score 1):

You always send variables as `String` the code on the server interprets the data as it wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Send the data as you already are doing. Server side: Parse and validate the data e.g.

```
If(int.tryparse(datareceived)) 
{
     Response.write("success");
}
else 
     Response.write("bad data");
```

Comment: Guys... the server side is not on my control :)